# Компилятор gcc не срабатывает после ввода данных

Tags: c, gcc, компилятор

Изучаю язык си на линуксе. Компилятор gcc. Пишу простые программки. При вызове `scanf` ввожу значения и жму энтер, но он никак не реагирует, затем ввожу любое значение и он начинает работать с первым введенным значением. подскажите что можно сделать, чтобы он сразу срабатывал?

ubuntu, в любом эмуляторе терминала работает одинаково, zsh, gcc -v 7.1.1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1, num2;

    printf("enter num1\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &num1);
    getchar();
    printf("enter num2\n");
    scanf("%d\n", &num2);
    getchar();
    printf("you entered %d and %d\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

на выходе получаю вот такое

```
enter num1
4
5
enter num2
6
7
you entered 4 and 6
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66050/discussion-on-question-by-kem-ozn--gcc-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> scanf("%d\n", &num1);
> getchar();
> ```

Что это делает по задумке?

- Считывает число.
- Считывает перевод строки.

Что это делает реально?

- Считывает число.
- Считывает все идущие подряд переводы строк до тех пор, пока не встретит другой символ. Но, т. к. ввод буферизированный, то после того символа тоже где-то нужен перевод строки (ну или EOF, но при консольном вводе это вряд ли).
- Считывает тот самый символ gechar'ом.

Как надо сделать?

```
scanf("%d", &num1);
```

Всё. scanf сам умеет пропускать пробелы перед всеми форматами кроме символов.

Если вдруг потом понадобится считывать символ, то надо будет перед ним пропустить порбелы:

```
scanf(" "), scanf("%c", &ch);
```

Обращаю внимание, что я разделил сыитывание на 2 вызова на случай, если порбельных символов там не окажется.

Comment: учитывая сложности автора, стоит *полный* минимальный пример рабочий показать.

Comment: @jfs, да ладно? просто `\n` убрать и `getchar()`.

Comment: спасибо) все понятно)

Comment: @kemozn, в таком случае прими ответ, который тебе помог, нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вызываете и `scanf()` и `getchar()`. Первая заносит значение в переменную, а вторая просто ждет когда вы введете какой-нибудь символ. Уберите `getchar()`.

**EDIT**: И еще уберите "\n" из `scanf()`. Он и так переведет курсор на новую строку. Теперь работает.

Comment: Неверно. Не поможет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Подправил.

Comment: Если убрать `\n`, то `getchar()` можно оставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тоже вариант

Answer (score -1):

Когда-то давно сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. Можно попробовать поставить после `scanf`:

```
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: можно чуть подробнее. как именно его вставить?

Comment: Как это должно помочь, когда ты находишься внутри другой функции?

Comment: это принудительное освобождение буферов ввода/вывода буферов. Стандартный ввод и вывод. Так что пофигу.